# add Tab via DataExtension Silverstripe3

Tags: silverstripe

I was wondering if it is possible to add a Tab via a DataExtension? The FieldList argument passed to  updateCMSFields appears to output a DataExtensions new fields onto the Details Tab.  So my first attempt was to push my Fields there:

```
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)  {  
    $secureFilesTab = $fields;
    $secureFilesTab->push(new HeaderField(_t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSTITLE', 'Group Access')));
    $secureFilesTab->push(new TreeMultiselectField('GroupPermissions', _t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSFIELD', 'Group Access Permissions')));
}
```

This works fine, but when I save a value, the CMS loads the data from the Tree_View and List_View tabs onto the Details Tab. Mentioned in comments below is the fact that this is a DataExtension for Folder.

I then tried using code from the FormScaffolder to add a new Tab:

```
public function UpdateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
    $fields->push(new TabSet('Root', $secureFilesTab = new Tab('Security')));
$secureFilesTab->setTitle(_t('SiteTree.TABSECURITY', 'Security'));
}
```

This changes the tab icons all to the Tree_View icons and places my new DataExtension fields on all tabs.

What is the proper way to add tabs via a DataExtension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use addFieldsToTab() to add new fields to an existing tab or a new one, as you would when using getCMSFields() on DataObjects.

```
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)  {  
    if ($this->owner->ClassName != 'Folder' ){
        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Security', array(
            new HeaderField(_t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSTITLE', 'Group Access')),
            new TreeMultiselectField('GroupPermissions', _t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSFIELD', 'Group Access Permissions'))
        ));     
    }
    if ($this->owner->ClassName == 'Folder' ){
        $fields->push(new HeaderField(_t('IMAFOLDER', 'I am a folder')));       
    }
}
```

The Security tab, if not found, will be created by passing 'Root.Security' as the first argument. The dot notation is used to create the nested structure of tabset and tabs. It is not possible to simple push a new tabset with the same name ("Root"), as there's already such a tabset. If you need to do further manipulations on your tabs, you can access their instance using $fields->findOrMakeTab('TabSet.Tab'), ie $fields->findOrMakeTab('Root.Content');

Comment: I have edited the answer : there was a typo in the code (addFieldsToTab as opposed to addFieldsToTabs)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. When I pass Root.Security to addFieldsToTab I get the following error: Error at framework/forms/FieldList.php line 295: FieldList::addFieldToTab() Tried to add a tab to object 'FieldList' - 'Root' didn't exist.Any thoughts?

Comment: I have tried the snippet above on two decorators : one for page and another one for member, and in both cases I could see a new Tab called security, with the expected fields. Maybe you can give us a bit more context? Like what are you decorating? Does the decorated DataObject rely on scaffolding for building its set of fields (or performs a parent::getCMSFields() before adding more fields definition)? It seems that the main Tabset Root is not built somehow, so something upstream is not right maybe?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. I am extending File/Folder, so I am working in AssetAdmin. When I do var_dump($fields->first()) I receive the name field which is present on the DetailsView tab of the extended Folder's CMS page. So it seems that the $fields argument in this case is the FieldList found in the DetailsView Tab?

Comment: Try with 

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields){
        if ($this->owner->ClassName != 'Folder' ){
            $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Security', array(
                new HeaderField(_t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSTITLE', 'Group Access')),
                new TreeMultiselectField('GroupPermissions', _t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSFIELD', 'Group Access Permissions'))
            ));  
        }
    }

This works for me for files. That's a start. I'm not sure if you want this to work for folders too?

Comment: The detail view for folders doesn't have a tabbing system, so you might just have to push your fields straight away

public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields){
 if ($this->owner->ClassName != 'Folder' ){
  $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Security', array(
   new HeaderField(_t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSTITLE', 'Group Access')),
   new TreeMultiselectField('GroupPermissions', _t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSFIELD', 'Group Access Permissions'))
   ));  
  }
  if ($this->owner->ClassName == 'Folder' ){
   $fields->push(new HeaderField(_t('SecureFiles.GROUPACCESSTITLE', 'folder Access')));  
 }
}

Comment: I have edited my answer so it's clearer than in comments. Sorry about the mess :-)

Comment: Thank so much for all the clarifications. So it seems that what I was doing initially in my first example is the solution. I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problem to enable tabs in Member extension, in function

```
public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
```

finally it started to work after I removed fields order

```
$fields->changeFieldOrder($order);
```

try it, maybe it helps you.

Comment: This has happened to me twice. Thank you for this answer it jump started my memory.